# Can use @Service objects as @Controllers?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a server that's primarily serving up a JSON API. Currently we have @Controllers that straightforwardly delegate REST endpoints to methods in @Service classes.

This is making for a lot of unnecessary boilerplate code. Am I likely to run into issues if I simply annotate my @Service classes with the @Controller and @RequestMapping annotations (e.g. screws up transaction calls? Problems with dependencies between services?)

Answer (score 4):

If you use both `@Service` and `@Controller` on the same bean there is a good chance you will create two beans for one class which is generally not what you want.

This happens because `@Controller` are usually loaded in a child context (dispatcher servlet).

If all your beans are loaded in the dispatcher servlet context you will be fine.

EDIT: I answered this in my iPhone so I couldn't go into detail.

I say *good chance* it will be a problem because It really has nothing to do with the type of annotations you use but rather the component scanning and how that component scanning is assigned to application contexts.

What most people do is scan for components with `@Service` to be loaded by the root `WebApplicationContext` which can be the same as the dispatcher servlet context but often is not.

Let me give you an example:

Typically you see an applicationContext.xml with the following:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.blah">
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

Followed by a dispatch servlet context XML with the following:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.blah" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

Notice how the first one excludes `@Controller` and the second explicitly includes.

That being said if you only have one WebApplicationContext and its shared with the dispatcher servlet then you can annotate `@Service` with `@RequestMapping` and it should work just fine not that I recommend that.

Comment: how can i know if spring have created 2 duplicate bean ? when can i see them ?

Comment: Annotating the type with 2 `@Component` specializations does not in itself create two beans.

Comment: It really has nothing to do with the type of annotations he uses but rather the component scanning and how that component scanning is assigned to application contexts.

Comment: useful explaination @AdamGent

Answer (score 1):

The MVC pattern exists for a good reason, let each layer does their job and have a low coupling between them. Each stereotype has a reason to exists too.

What kind of boilerplate code you are talking about? @Controller and @RequestMapping are straightforward.

Comment: Say I have 10 service classes each with 10 methods to be made made public to a REST API. Instead of implementing each service class and annotating methods to be exported as the REST APIs,I need to create an additional 10 controller classes, with 10 methods each with a body that is simply return service.method(param1,param2). I now have two chunks of code that need to be kept in sync -- any changes in one necessitates changes in the other (=high coupling). If service=controller, dependencies of the controller are still decoupled from the service's implementation and non-@RequestMapping methods.

Comment: The point is you could change your service layer without changing the REST layer, you could handle some default case in your service layer. What you are suggesting is basically ditch a good architecture (seperate the core of yuor application from the outside usage) for an inconvenience. Also when yuo need to make changes to your service layer that should be hard as you are changing the heart of your application.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I likely to run into issues if I simply annotate my `@Service`
>   classes with the `@Controller` and `@RequestMapping` annotations

You don't need to annotate the type with `@Controller` if it is annotated with `@Service`. Just make sure the **type** has a `@RequestMapping` annotation. The `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` which handles mapping your controllers' handler methods checks for both `@Controller` and `@RequestMapping` annotation at the type level. You need either.

Other than that, it's just a question of design and separation of concerns. At the technical Spring level you won't have any other issues.

(Note that you'll have to load the bean through the `DispatcherServlet`'s `WebApplicationContext` for the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` to pick it up.)

Answer (score 0):

@Controllers are to delegate entry and end point to one request/response.

@Service are to providing the logic to those @Controllers, logic that must to be unknown by the @Controllers.

In @Controllers you must to @Autowired your @Services dependencies. And in your @Services your other logic dependencies like DAOs, etc...

One typical Rest @Controller could look like this:

```
@Controller
public class UserWSController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}")
    @ResponseBody
    public User getUserPublicInfo(@PathVariable int userId) {

        return this.userService.getUserById(userId);
    }

}
```